# Koszul algebras among finite dimensional commutative algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra, koszul-algebras

Given a local commutative artinian algebra $A$ of the form $K[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ with quadratic ideal $I$ and $K$ a field.

> Question 1: Is there a computer algebra system that can check whether such an algebra is Koszul?

> Question 2: Is there a classification (or a research program for such a classification) of Koszul algebras among this class of algebras? Maybe at least with some more restrictions like $A$ being Gorenstein and small $n$ like $n \leq 3$ or $n \leq 4$?

Comment: Decades have passed since I was working on quadratic algebras, and I do not remember anything anymore.  But I think that Question 1 is long known to be algorithmically unsolvable.  My book (Chapter 6 Section 6) gives a reference: D.J. Anick, "Generic algebras and CW-complexes", 1987.  On the other hand, Question 2 for $n\le2$ is not only long known, but also very easy even without the commutativity and Artinianity assumptions. You can solve it yourself as a homework or look up in my book (Chapter 6 Section 5).  The book is "Quadratic algebras", by A. Polishchuk and L. Positselski.

Comment: @LeonidPositselski Thanks, I will take a look in your book. I edited question 2 to also include $n \leq 3$ or $n\leq 4$ (it was $n \leq 2$ before). Maybe there is a (partial) classification also in this case.

Comment: Yes, $\dim A_2\le2$ and arbitrary $n=\dim A_1$ was completely classified in Backelin's dissertation (even in the noncommutative case).  This was back in the early '80s. For $n=3$ (and maybe some other small $n$), people did computer-assisted searches and classified something.  One relatively recent paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00336

Comment: @LeonidPositselski Thanks. If you want you can turn your comments also into an answer.